# node.js send more datas

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm working on a project, where the server send a string to the client, between binary datas

```
socket.write('\u0000', 'binary');
socket.write('welcome', 'utf8');
socket.write('\uffff', 'binary');
```

It works, but it sends one after another. It is possible to send the whole string and the binary in one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with [socket.write()](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#socket.write). You will need to have one encoding type.

What you can do is, convert the utf8 string to binary type and send all at once:

```
socket.write(YOUR_DATA, 'binary');
```

Comment: Try this out: http://blog.sarathonline.com/2009/02/javascript-convert-strings-to-binary.html . 1. Convert the string to binary, 2. concat all binary together, 3. send

Comment: to convert the utf8 string to binary, we have to use Buffers, but I cant understand it: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.1.100/api.html#buffers-3